# NRE to savings account

Tags: india, savings, non-resident, money-transfer, business

I am living abroad for the past three years on a student visa, and therefore fall in the 'NRI' category. I have a NRE account where I had sent some funds from abroad.

Lately, I have been thinking to transfer this money to my savings account in another bank in India. Further, I want to invest this money in a business which involves bank account linking, transferring and receiving money (in Indian currency only and where I can not link my NRE account).

I understand the following: I can transfer money from my NRE account to my savings account, NRE account is tax free and savings bank account is taxable.

If I earn some profit on this business and it is taxable, I can file the tax return.

What I want to confirm is whether this process of transferring money from my NRE to my savings account and using it for business is legally 'ok'?

Somebody got me worried about this being in violation of FEMA rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> have been thinking to transfer this money to my savings account in another bank in India.

As per regulation you can't have ordinary savings account. Please convert this to NRO savings account.

> I can transfer money from my NRE account to my savings account, NRE account is tax free and savings bank account is taxable.

Any interest in NRO account is taxable. All credits in NRO accounts are scrutinized. Credits from NRE account are not taxable. However if there are any income that is generated; it is taxable.

> If I earn some profit on this business and it is taxable, I can file the tax return.

This is fine. It would be a good practice to keep filing NIL returns for the NRO accounts even if you are not doing anything.

> What I want to confirm is whether this process of transferring money from my NRE to my savings account and using it for business is legally 'ok'?

Transferring money is fine. There is no restriction. If you are doing some business, then please consult a CA. There are some approvals required. If you are investing in stocks / shares you will have to open relevant NRI Demat / trading accounts. Similarly buying a house is also fine.

Please note that money in NRO can't be freely repatriated. There is a limit of USD 1 million per year.

Comment: India sure does seem to have a complicated set of bank accounts!!

Comment: @RonJohn Ya it is when one is Non Resident. It allows better segregation of funds, reporting and management.

Comment: Because resident and nonresident interest and dividends are taxed differently?

Comment: @RonJohn Yes. But more complicated. A non resident needs to open NRE [Non Resident External] Account. All Bank interest from this is tax free. Any investment from here can be repatriated easily. Capital assets purchased from here can be repatriated to the extent of funding. Dividends are anyways tax free for everyone and Dividend Distribution tax is paid by company. Existing savings account is designated / changed as Non Resident Ordinary. All interest here is taxable. The categorization allows Govt to know the flight risk of the funds here.

Comment: "*allows Govt to know the flight risk of the funds here.*"  Ah...

Comment: I think I get the bigger picture. To be very clear, I want to trade in crypto and earn some profit from the price difference. Channel would be: send money from current country -> NRE account -> savings account -> crypto exchange -> transfer crypto assets to current country -> sell and send money to NRE account.. and so on. But as per your answer, seems like it wouldn't be a very healthy way to do it.

Comment: @Karandeep There is very less clarity on Crypto currency. RBI has issued caution. Tax wise it is not clear if it can be treated as capital gains ... best you do it overseas.It would anyway be expensive in India. Plus converting funds would be expensive. Round tripping of funds is an issue and volition of FEMA.

Comment: @Dheer Would it also be an issue if I could somehow link my NRE account to crypto exchange? Then the channel I explained in comment above, could be ok for FEMA? As funds from abroad are being used and then sent back abroad again?